# Publish Apple App Store in Visual Studio Apache Cordova project

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, code-signing

I have a Visual Studio Apache Cordova project and successfully published on Android Google Play. However, I have been struggling to find out how to publish it to "Apple App Store".

- "remotebuild" to Mac system and successfully running on debugging deivce (iPhone). [image: Debug mode "Remote Device"]
- But not able to deploy with release mode of "Remote Device" (Build is successful)

> Requesting deploy on remote iOS device for buildNumber 2765 on server https://remote-address:3000/cordova...
>   2>Failed to deploy iOS remote for build C:\PathToProject\bld\ios\Release\buildInfo.json to https://remote-address:3000/cordova :
>   2>Http 404: Installation failed: Check your provisioning profile
>   2>
>   2>Failed to deploy iOS remote for build C:\PathToProject\bld\ios\Release\buildInfo.json to https://remote-address:3000/cordova :
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Which I have already downloaded the Provisioning / Certificate for both Development and Distribution and configured to XCode --> Preference --> Accounts --> Apple ID and Signining Identities.

I tried to verify the .ipa file generated by "remotebuild" using command line as below

> codesign -v name.ipa

Saying

> code object is not signed at all

I also tried to code sign manually ([How to manually re-sign an IPA](http://blog.favo.org/post/21905923260/how-to-manually-re-sign-an-ipa-with-a-new)) but still saying that "code object is not signed at all"

"PhoneGap Build" also did not work

My questions are

1. Is there any way to configure the provisioning and certificate for iOS in Visual Studio Apache Cordova project?
2. Do I have to convert this Visual Studio Apache Cordova project to PhoneGap Project and load it on XCode and build with code sign?

Please help me to find a way to publish it on Apple App Store.

Comment: I face the same issue. Mirrh did you ever get this working? If so bounty available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367393/visual-studio-cordova-when-packaging-the-app-for-ios-how-to-add-the-provisioni

Answer (score 0):

You follow the same steps you would for any other app you publish to iTunes app store.  You need to open the Xcode project file created by Cordova in Xcode.  You set the correct provisioning profile in Xcode then perform an archive (note the current target needs to be an actual device, not the simulator).

After the archive is created you will be given the option to validate it.  Once it is validated you will be given the option to upload to it iTunes connect.   Note you need to setup everything in iTunes Connect before doing this.  You need to create your app id, any certificates, etc...