# Visual Studio Cordova: when packaging the app for IOS, how to add the provisioning profile to the code signing section of Build Settings for XCode?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

When using Visual Studio Cordova, I am following these instructions to publish the app to the Apple App Store:

http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/

After successfully creating the Certificate and Provisioning Profile, and then successfully downloading the Provisioning Profile (*.mobileprovision) file to my Mac, the instructions then say to "Double-click that file to install it and then add it to the Code signing section of Build Settings for Xcode."

But when I doubleclick, Xcode is launched but my project is not loaded. Now keep in mind that up until this point, I have only used the Mac as a dummy machine for remote build - I haven't actually used the Mac directly to do any coding in XCode directly. So I have no idea where the project is that I'm assuming was created when I did my remote build via the Windows machine.

So am I supposed to open up the project on the Mac to install the Provisioning Profile? Where would it be stored? What kind of file am I looking for (like what file extension).

I did find an XCode project created by VS Cordova at the following location (Users/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/XXX/cordovaApp/platforms/ios) but these xocde projects get created each time I make a new build in Visual Studio, so any changes I make to the XCode project from the Mac don't get used upon later builds.

Answer (score 2):

You can find provisioning profile setup information in this new document on the taco.visualstudio.com site. This is a fairly new article, so you may not have seen it yet:

http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#create-a-provisioning-profile

Specifically, it walks through how to install the provisioning profile in XCode.

Comment: I get the Dev provisioning profile setup properly, but am unable to get the Distrib. provisioning profile working. In particular, when trying to install the provisioning profile on my device "Navigate the location where you downloaded your provisioning profile, choose the file, and then choose the Install button." (from the instructions): Nothing seems to happen-XCode just returns to the listing page and no dist. provis. profile's installed on the device. When try to build from VS Cordova Release--> IOS-->Remote device shows "Http 404: Installation failed: Check your provisioning profile"

Comment: I have the development and distribution provisioning profiles created and available in XCode, but I still get "Http 404: Installation failed: Check your provisioning profile"  I can even see in VS Cordova when it builds, one line of the output log states: "Provisioning Profile: 253f08...." Which corresponds to the correct distribution provisioning profile. Any help is greatly appreciated. Been stuck for days...

Comment: @DouglasTimms i know its been a old post , here you successfully created the developer profile and you are trying to install distribution , for this Apple Guide says that _App Store provisioning profiles do not allow for a distribution built application to be installed on an Apple device. To install your distribution ready application on a device, you must create an Ad Hoc provisioning profile._ , so the bottom line is you are trying to install the distribution build on development device, which will not allow you to do it . for this....

Comment: @DouglasTimms .development device means the device which is added as a provisioned devices list. so in order to make it work do as follows:  in your member center try to create a distribution adhoc provision profile and then instal a build with that profile after that try to install with Distribution Provisioning profile without deleting that previous build then only it will allow to install the distribution build on the development provisioned devices. after a couple of research i came to know this point. please tell me you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could equip your provisioning profile to your Xcode application. You can use visual studio cordova for your development. Upon deployment use your remote access to "archive" the project on Xcode to upload to iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I came across from your comment on my similar question 
[Publish Apple App Store in Visual Studio Apache Cordova project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219120/publish-apple-app-store-in-visual-studio-apache-cordova-project?noredirect=1#comment56637246_33219120)
and it turns out that Apache Cordova needs to upgrade the version to support XCode 7

--iOS 9.x version bug fix

```
sudo cordova platform upgrade –g ios@3.9.2
```

If this doesn't work then You may want to copy the entire project to your workplace which is generated by remotebuild located at

```
Users/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/###/cordovaApp/platforms/ios
```

Open the project with XCode -> Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Provisioning Profile -> Make sure the Provisioning is set to Distribution Provisioning if you want to publish it otherwise set it to Development Provisioning for testing.

Please note that WHEN you upload the app to the App Store via XCode
THE **BITCODE** thingy is checked by default and this caused error but it doesn't say the error is related to BITCODE and It will show the error message saying something like Code Signing is not signed correctly.

UNCHECK the BITCODE before Upload to App Store

Upload App from XCode

Xcode -> Product -> Archive -> Validate -> After Validation is done -> Upload to App Store -> Uncheck Bitcoin -> Hit Next

These issues were pulling my hair out for couple of weeks.